# Why isn't the 'Add to Home Screen' prompt showing on my PWA app for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am building a PWA app. For which i require add to home screen prompt on mobile devices. But unfortunately, it is not appearing in mobile devices. I am able to see the install icon on desktop devices but not able to see popup on mobile devices.

**service-worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open("pwa").then(function (cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        "/",
        "/templates/classic-theme/css/style.css",
        "/templates/classic-theme/js/script.js",
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open("pwa").then(function (cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        cache.addAll([event.request.url]);

        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request);
      });
    })
  );
});
```

**script.js**

```
let installEvent = null;
let installButton = document.getElementById("install");
let enableButton = document.getElementById("enable");

if (!localStorage.getItem("pwa-enabled")) {
  localStorage.setItem("pwa-enabled", true);
}
if (localStorage["pwa-enabled"]) {
  startPwa();
}

function startPwa(firstStart) {
  localStorage["pwa-enabled"] = true;

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("/templates/classic-theme/js/service-worker.js")
      .then((registration) => {
        console.log("Service Worker is registered", registration);
        enableButton.parentNode.remove();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Registration failed:", err);
      });
  });

  window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Ready to install...");
    installEvent = e;
    document.getElementById("install").style.display = "initial";
  });

  setTimeout(cacheLinks, 500);

  function cacheLinks() {
    caches.open("pwa").then(function (cache) {
      let linksFound = [];
      document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function (a) {
        linksFound.push(a.href);
      });

      cache.addAll(linksFound);
    });
  }

  if (installButton) {
    installButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      installEvent.prompt();
    });
  }
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "short_name": "XYZ",
    "name": "XYZ",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "../../../storage/logo/favicon.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "../../../storage/logo/favicon.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "144x144"
        },
        {
            "src": "../../../storage/logo/favicon.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "https://example.com",
    "background_color": "rgba(0,189,98,0.15)",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "https://example.com",
    "theme_color": "rgba(0,189,98,0.15)"
}
```

I tried to solve using google and stackoverflow multiple resources but non of them worked.